# How to open file using POSIX interface (open(),write())

Tags: c, file, posix

I'm trying to open a file with the POSIX interface with the plan of then writing to it. However, I can't even get the file to open properly. I have checked similar questions but they don't seem to fix my problem.

So far I've got:

```
int file;
file = open(filename,O_CREAT | O_WRONLY); 
// I tried open(filename,O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0666) and other permission values to no avail
if(file == -1) {
    return 0;
}
//then would go on to write...
```

I would think that this would work after looking at the other problems people have had, I've also tried to put other flags in (which I didn't really expect to make a difference since I should only need the two I have) and include different permissions but no matter what I do it gives me file == -1. Normally I would use a FILE object but that can't be used in this case.

Comment: What was the `errno` value?

Comment: What is filename value

Comment: @baliman the filename is "something.bs"

Comment: @StaceyGirl errno = 13

Comment: @WhiteTomatoes And what does that mean? You don'r provide enough information to solve this. You might have no permissions to create files there - we have no chance of knowing that.

Comment: @StaceyGirl well I have created files here before using a FILE object, that's sort of why I'm confused as to why this POSIX method of creating a file won't work.

Comment: Put `fprintf(stderr, "opening %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));` as the first statement of the `if (file == -1) { ... }` block.  Add includes of errno.h, string.h, and stdio.h to the top of the program if they aren't already there.  Tell us _exactly_ what is printed.

Comment: `errno` code numbers vary from system to system, so they don't tell us anything useful.  The strings produced by `strerror(errno)` _are_ useful.

Comment: Incidentally, `open` must be written with three arguments whenever `O_CREAT` is in the flags.  This probably isn't your immediate problem but it seems you are confused about whether you need the third argument, so let's clear that up now: you do.

Comment: @zwol the output of the fprintf is: opening something.bs: Permission denied

Comment: OK, this means that `something.bs` already exists and you don't have permission to write to it.  Please edit your question and paste in the COMPLETE AND UNEDITED output of `ls -la`, run in the directory where you are running this program.  It would also be useful to see the output of the `id` command.

Comment: @zwol This just guided me to my solution, thanks. I didn't realize the file was actually being created even though it was making file = -1. Once I realized it had been created I did ls -la and realized it was limited to only read I changed its permissions and now it works.